# Выделение чисел с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как написать регулярное выражение, чтобы из строки цифр и символов, разделенных пробелом, выделить только числа? 
Например, строка:

```
123 -111.9 ww1 111 q2q2 1
```

В итоге должно получиться:

```
123 -111.9 111 1
```

Использую выражение `[-+]\\d+`, но тогда последняя единичка видится, как `1\n` и отбрасывается.

Как быть?

Comment: @alexolut, зря ты правишь недописанные вопросы...

Comment: @Qwertiy что значит "недописанные"?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Extract float/double value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385558/extract-float-double-value)

Comment: @alexolut, то, что приведённая регулярка вообще не взаимодействует со `\n`, а значит, описанное поведение не воспроизводится.

Comment: Помог мой ответ? Пожалуйста, проверьте ответы и пометьте луший как решение, щёлкнув серую галочку напротив ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте границы слов и опциональную группу:

```
[-+]?\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/0l8ocn/1)

**Подробности**:

- `[-+]?` - 1 или 0 знаков `-` или `+`
- `\b`  - граница слова (начало)
- `\d+` - 1+ цифр
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - 1 или 0 последовательностей:

  - `\.` - точка
  - `\d+` - 1+ цифр
- `\b` - граница слова (конец)

[Java-демо](http://ideone.com/Aeqppw):

```
String str = "123 -111.9 ww1 111 q2q2 1";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("[-+]?\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\b");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    res.add(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(res);
// => [123, -111.9, 111, 1]
```

Comment: Вместо `\.` думаю лучше использовать `[.,]`, для большей универсальности, тогда получается выражение: `[-+]?\b\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?\b`.

Comment: @gt22: Тут можно и дальше совершенствовать, как сочинения по литературе (или дипломные/курсовые работы). Например, [`[-+]?\b\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/0l8ocn/3), [`[-+]?\b(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/0l8ocn/4), [`[-+]?\b(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/0l8ocn/5). Только тут речь идёт о поиске в тексте, а не валидации строки, поэтому такая экстраточность не требуется.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `[-+]?\b(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+(?:[eE][-+]?\d+|[x×*]10(\^\d+|[⁻⁺]?[⁰¹²³⁴-⁹]+))?)?\b` Лучше, мне кажется, некуда. Разве что if then else на точки и запятые добавить, но я яве этого делать, к сожалению, нельзя.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия У вас тут проблема с границами слова, `-12,123.34×10⁻¹` [не найдёт](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydc6z4nr).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew вообще некорректно в данном случае использовать \b, так как он включает в себя точки и запятые, лучше будет использовать (?:(?<=\s)|^) и (?:(?=\s)|$). `[-+]?(?:(?<=\s)|^)(?:\d{1,3}(?:(?:,\d{3})*|\d*))(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][-+]?\d+|[x×*]10(?:\^[-+]?\d+|[⁻⁺]?[⁰¹²³⁴-⁹]+))?(?:(?=\s)|$)`. Я ещё немного видоизменил, чтобы было вообще идеально. Ранее не находило 1e10.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия Гораздо "идеальнее" вместо `(?:(?<=\s)|^)` и `(?:(?=\s)|$)` использовать `(?<!\S)` и `(?!\S)`. Но судя по вопросу, такие изыски тут просто не нужны, они будут только смущать.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew не могу не оставить. `[-+]?(?<!\S)(?:\d{1,3}(?:(?:,\d{3})*|\d*))(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][-+]?\d+|[x×*]10(?:\^[-+]?\d+|[⁻⁺]?[⁰¹²³⁴-⁹]+))?(?!\S)`. Красота!

Comment: @ИмяФамилия [Нет, не то](https://regex101.com/r/lxMGg8/1).  `(?<!\S)[-+]?\d{1,3}(?:(?:,\d{3})*|\d*)(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][-+]?\d+|[x×*]10(?:\^[-+]?\d+|[⁻⁺]?[⁰¹²³⁴-⁹]+))?(?!\S)` [сойдёт](https://regex101.com/r/lxMGg8/2) в таком случае.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ой блин. Да, тупанул.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать следующее регулярное выражение:

```
[-+]?\b[\d+.,]+\b
```

[Результат](https://regex101.com/r/0l8ocn/2)

Comment: [Это выражение не надёжно](https://regex101.com/r/awUFgY/1).

Comment: Коллеги! Спасибо за помощь! Вы очень помогли! :) Я новичок!